# Callback on push notification open Android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I know we can launch activities on notification open like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
Intent targetIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
//...
```

But what if, instead of lunch an activity, I want to run a callback, like some *onPushOpen*, so to choose there how to handle the notification click?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an activity in your manifest, call it NotificationClickHandlerActivity, which you will set as the target for the pending intent of your notification instead of MainActivity.

In the onCreate method of this new activity, just call getIntent, based on the information in the intent (action, categories, extras) determine what needs to be opened next, start the new target activity which you determined or do some other action, then call finish from inside onCreate and return immediately.

If an activity calls finish in onCreate like this handler, it will never be shown to the user, so he will not be aware that it even exists, all he'll see is the other activity which you potentially launch from it.

Also, keep in mind that you should not do long running operations in the onCreate method of this handler activity as they will be executed on the UI thread and will block your app from responding to user input. If you have to do something longer running, put it inside an async task subclass (either STATIC nested class of the handler activity, or completely separate class), then start an instance of this task from the onCreate method, and call finish right after the task is started. The task will continue running in the background. If the task needs a context to do whatever it has to do, make sure you pass it an application context by calling getApplicationContext, and don't pass the activity itself otherwise you will have memory leaks.

Answer (score -2):

You could use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to achive that. Just post some event like onPushOpen() and catch it anywhere you want. Make smth like:

```
Intent targetIntent = new Intent(this, NaughtyActivity.class);
```

And make NaughtyActivity use no layout. Use it just to post the event and finish.